# Multiple SFINAE class template specialisations using void_t

Tags: c++, c++17, template-specialization, sfinae, partial-specialization

Are multiple class template specialisations valid, when each is distinct only between patterns involving template parameters in non-deduced contexts?

A common example of `std::void_t` uses it to define a trait which reveals whether a type has a member `typedef` called "type". Here, a single specialisation is employed. This could be extended to identify say whether a type has *either* a member `typedef` called "type1", or one called "type2". The C++1z code below compiles with GCC, but not Clang. Is it legal?

```
template <class, class = std::void_t<>>
struct has_members : std::false_type {};

template <class T>                      
struct has_members<T, std::void_t<typename T::type1>> : std::true_type {};

template <class T>                                                        
struct has_members<T, std::void_t<typename T::type2>> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: Don't see anything wrong offhand. What exactly is clang's error message say?

Comment: Clang says that the second specialisation is a redefinition,

Comment: isn't it right for a class that has both `type1` and `type2`?

Comment: Off-topic, but it's weird to write `bool_constant<true>` instead of the much shorter `true_type` (and likewise for `false`)

Comment: This hinges on when `using` must be grokked -- when declared, or when template substitution happens. Clang is grokking it when the declaration occurs (seems obvious that's what it's doing). This sounds obviously wrong to me. I think that clang is wrong, here.

Comment: Try an experiment. Instead of using `std::void_t`, add a declaration: `template<typename T> struct is_void { typedef void type; };`, and use `typename is_void<typename T::type1>::type` and `typename is_void<typename T::type2>:type`, and see what clang says about that.

Comment: @Barry Followed your "off-topic" suggestion on `bool_constant` - what was I thinking?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Clang compiles that.

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=void_t

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a rule that partial specializations have to be more specialized than the primary template - both of your specializations follow that rule. But there isn't a rule that states that partial specializations can never be ambiguous. It's more that - if instantiation leads to ambiguous specialization, the program is ill-formed. But that ambiguous instantiation has to happen first!

<s>It appears that clang is suffering from [CWG 1558](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558) here and is overly eager about substituting in `void` for `std::void_t`</s>.

This is [CWG 1980](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1980) almost exactly:

> In an example like
>
> ```
> template<typename T, typename U> using X = T;
> template<typename T> X<void, typename T::type> f();
> template<typename T> X<void, typename T::other> f();
> ```
>
> it appears that the second declaration of `f` is a redeclaration of the first but distinguishable by SFINAE, i.e., equivalent but not functionally equivalent.

If you use the non-alias implementation of `void_t`:

```
template <class... Ts> struct make_void { using type = void; };
template <class... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
```

then clang allows the two different specializations. Sure, instantiating `has_members` on a type that has both `type1` and `type2` typedefs errors, but that's expected.

Comment: 1558 only deals with whether substitution applies at all, not declaration matching, which is a whole different beast. This is closer to CWG 1980. The whole business of alias templates being transparent but not completely transparent proves tricky :)

Comment: @T.C. Heh, was looking for issues that contained "specialization." Bad filter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's correct, or at least, not if we instantiate has_members with a type that has both type1 and type2 nested, the result would be two specializations that are

```
has_members<T, void>
```

which would not be valid.  Until the code is instantiated I think it's ok, but clang is rejecting it early.  On g++, your fails with this use-case, once instantiated:

```
struct X
{
    using type1 = int;
    using type2 = double;
};

int main() {
    has_members<X>::value;
}
```

The error message is doesn't seem to describe the actual problem, but it at least is emitted:

```
<source>:20:21: error: incomplete type 'has_members<X>' used in nested name specifier
     has_members<X>::value;
                     ^~~~~
```

If you instantiate it with a type that has only type1 *or* type2 but not both, 
then g++ compiles it cleanly.  So it's objecting to the fact that the members are both present, causing conflicting instantiations of the template.

To get the disjunction, I think you'd want code like this:

```
template <class, class = std::void_t<>>
struct has_members : std::bool_constant<false> {};

template <class T>
struct has_members<T, std::enable_if_t<
        std::disjunction<has_member_type1<T>, has_member_type2<T>>::value>> : 
    std::bool_constant<true> {};
```

This assumes you have traits to determine has_member_type1 and has_member_type2 already written.

Comment: I understand that this is not valid with types containing both members. The code is only an example to help articulate the main question.