# Specialization based on array size validity

Tags: c++, template-specialization

Trying to specialize based on validity of array size:

```
// base template
template<int p, typename T = void>
struct absolute {
    operator int () const { return 0; }
};

// positive case template
template<int p>
struct absolute<p, typename std::void_t<int[p]>> {
    operator int () const { return p; }
};

// negative case template
template<int p>
struct absolute<p, typename std::void_t<int[-p]>> {
    operator int () const { return -p; }
};


int main() {
    std::cout << absolute<5>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << absolute<-5>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << absolute<0>() << std::endl;
}
```

---

### Issue #1:

Above code [works nicely with gcc but fails to compile with clang](https://godbolt.org/z/SLTPxd).

Clang generates the error: ***redefinition of template struct 'absolute'***

**Who is right?**

---

### Issue #2:

[Both with gcc and with clang](https://godbolt.org/z/BzHbUV) (if we remove the negative specialization to bring clang back to the game), not clear why `absolute<0>()` selects the base template. [There is nothing wrong](https://godbolt.org/z/sfSxam) with `int[0]` as well as with `std::void_t<int[0]>` which seems to be more specialized:

```
// base template
template<int p, typename T = void>
struct absolute {
    operator int () const { return -1; }
};

// positive case template
template<int p>
struct absolute<p, typename std::void_t<int[p]>> {
    operator int () const { return p; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << absolute<5>() << std::endl; // 5
    std::cout << absolute<0>() << std::endl; // -1, why not 0?
}
```

And... if the base template is just declared without implementation, as:

```
// base template
template<int p, typename T = void>
struct absolute;
```

[Both gcc and clang would fail to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/U_wubG), complaining on ***invalid use of incomplete type*** for the call: `absolute<0>()`. Even though it seems to fit the specialized case.

**Why is that?**

Comment: `template<int p>
struct absolute<p, typename std::void_t<int[p]>>`
and `template<int p>
struct absolute` isn't that a duplicate?

Comment: `int[0]` is forbidden by the ISO C++ standard https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.array#1 "its value shall be greater than zero"

Comment: @L.F. so not failing here: https://godbolt.org/z/sfSxam is a bug with both clang and gcc?

Comment: @AmirKirsh You forgot to disable extensions. https://godbolt.org/z/RB96uc

Comment: Compiles in MSVC as well.

Comment: @L.F. can you provide a reference in the standard indicating that `int[-p]` is not allowed in that context? indeed `-pedantic-errors` raise compilation error on that in gcc, but in other context such an expression would be allowed

Comment: @AmirKirsh There's no problem with `int[-p]`.  It's `int[0]` that's causing the error.

Comment: @L.F. **for issue #1**: doesn't seem like that: https://godbolt.org/z/T6ftP9

Comment: another nice approach, that works well, with functions overloading: https://godbolt.org/z/X_rg5S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding Clang's redefinition error, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948990/multiple-sfinae-class-template-specialisations-using-void-t).

Originally template-ids of alias templates such as `std::void_t` would simply be replaced with their aliasing type without checking the arguments for substitution failure. This was changed with [CWG issue 1558](https://wg21.link/cwg1558). This only changed the standard to require substitution failure in the template arguments to be done, but doesn't clarify whether two templates that would be equivalent after replacing the alias should be considered equivalent. Clang considers them to be equivalent, but GCC doesn't. This is the open [CWG issue 1980](https://wg21.link/cwg1980).

---

With `-pedantic-errors` GCC reports a hard error already for

```
std::cout << absolute<5>() << std::endl;
```

in the specialization

```
template<int p>
struct absolute<p, typename std::void_t<int[-p]>>
```

because supposedly the array size is not a constant expression. The size of an array must be a converted constant expression of type `std::size_t`. A converted constant expression may only use non-narrowing conversions. So it is true that `-p` with `p = 5` converted to `std::size_t` is not a constant expression, making the type `int[-p]` ill-formed, but I think that should cause a substitution failure, not a hard error. [[temp.deduct/8]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#deduct-8) of the C++17 standard (draft N4659) says:

> If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type deduction fails. An invalid type or expression is one that would be ill-formed, with a diagnostic required, if written using the substituted arguments.

And this applies here. The non-normative examples given in following the quote even include negative array sizes as example for substitution failure.

It is particularly strange that for `absolute<-5>()` GCC does *not* report the equivalent error on the

```
template<int p>
struct absolute<p, typename std::void_t<int[p]>>
```

specialization, where `int[p]` would evaluate to `int[-5]` which also doesn't have a converted constant expression size.

---

`absolute<0>()` chooses the primary template, because array sizes are required to be larger than zero, making the partial specializations both non-viable. Zero-sized arrays are a language extension that can be disabled with `-pedantic-errors` in GCC and Clang.

Comment: Implementing our own version of `void_t` works for both clang and gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/-2C8mJ so it seems related to CWG issue 1558... or does it handle also CWG issue 1980?

Comment: @AmirKirsh With your definition you are also circumventing CWG issue 1980. Both of them are related to how alias templates which resolve to non-dependent types are handled. Your definition resolves to `make_void<Ts...>::type`, which is a dependent type.

Comment: @AmirKirsh I did not realize that GCC only ever complains about the one specializations size not being a constant expression. I have updated the answer to reflect that and it seems to make it even more clear to me that GCC is inconsistent.