# Why using SFINAE to find if a method exists fails with std::vector::begin

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm looking for a way to detect if a template class has the methods `begin`, `end` and `resize`.

I tried a modified version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257382/4602726):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// SFINAE test
template <typename T>
class has_method
{
    typedef char one;
    struct two { char x[2]; };

    template <typename C> static one test( decltype(&C::begin) ) ;
    template <typename C> static two test(...);    

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << has_method<std::vector<int>>::value << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

However this prints 0. What is funny is that this will work with `cbegin` and `cend` but not with `begin`, `end` and `resize`. User defined classes implementing those methods works fine though.

I've tried this with both g++ and with Visual Studio 19 and I get the same results so this doesn't seem to be related to the compiler or the STL's implementation.

Comment: It has to do with the fact that std::vector's `begin()` is overloaded (const-overloaded to be specific).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`std::vector` has an oveloaded `begin`: one overload is `const` and the other one is not.

The compiler doesn't know which overload to use when you write `&C::begin`, so it treats this ambiguity as an error, which gets detected by SFINAE.

Instead of forming a pointer to `begin`, just call it:

```
// ...
template <typename C> static one test( decltype(void(std::declval<C &>().begin())) * );
// ...
```

(In case it's not obvious, if you're trying to detect a function with parameters, you must provide arguments, e.g. `.resize(0)` (or perhaps `.resize(std::size_t{})`) instead of just `.resize()`.)

And here's another, shorter solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_begin : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_begin<T, decltype(void(std::declval<T &>().begin()))> : std::true_type {};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << has_begin<std::vector<int>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

And here's a fancy C++20 `requires`-based solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
concept has_begin = requires(T t) {t.begin();};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << has_begin<std::vector<int>> << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @TommyD I suggest posting a new answer (if nobody showed those approaches yet). Or at least amending the original answer instead of completely replacing the code.

Comment: @TommyD the answer you quote is from before C++11 and targeting pre C++11 the answer is fine as is. Second answer on same question is already more up to date

Comment: why is the `void( ... )` needed? in the "shorter" solution

Comment: @idclev463035818 It is to remove the ambiguity of the returned value of the method.

You can create void statement like this and give it any parameters. Since this always creates a `noop` then any parameter becomes valid and thus the ambiguity is nullified since it doesn't matter which version is taken. To sum it up: cast into a callable type -> call the method -> pass it into a parameter to a void statement, that effectively is void f(...){}  and then transform this into a type to put inside the template argument; if this fail the other definition is used as per SFINAE.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have a suggestion. It should be indicated that the inside `decltype(void(...))` it is a full function call sample that has to be present (e.g. `.resize(0)`)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Well, the resulting type must be `void`, to match the default argument. I could've done `std::void_t<decltype(blahblah.begin())>` with the same effect, but Clang sometimes [does weird things with it with it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45948990/2752075), so I avoid it.

Comment: Your version is also better because it is unspecified what happens (including making your program ill-formed) if you take the address of a standard library function: http://eel.is/c++draft/constraints#namespace.std-6