# accessing class member regardless of it being a function or a data member

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I want to write a generic accessor for a class member regardless whether it is a function or or a data member:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace traits
{
    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct _name;

    template <typename T>
    struct _name<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().name)>>
    {
        constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(const T &t) const
        {
            return t.name;
        }
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct _name<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().name())>>
    {
        constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(const T &t) const
        {
            return t.name();
        }
    };

    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) name(const T &t)
    {
        return _name<T>{}(t);
    }
}

#include <string>

struct beb
{
   std::string name = "beb";
};

struct bob
{
   std::string name() const
   {
       return "bob";
   }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << traits::name(bob());
    std::cout << traits::name(beb());
}
```

I am using SFINAE with `void_t` specialization, but it works with only single specialization. Otherwise it gives an error saying `error C2953: 'traits::_name<T,void>': class template has already been defined`.

MSVC latest: https://godbolt.org/z/h9WT58z8P - does not compile
GCC 12.2: https://godbolt.org/z/vc3K1M7x5 - compiles
Clang 15.0.0: https://godbolt.org/z/dqGEMfYWK - does not compile

1. Should this code compile? (It compiles only for GCC)
2. How to make it compilable?

---

`_name` is a customization point within a `traits` namespace. By default it accesses `name` using `name` or `name()`. But one can provide a specialization to use, for example `getName()`.

Comment: What's your expectation when it's a functor - i.e., a member, that's also callable? Or a function pointer?

Comment: @lorro this is a legit but somehow rare occasion. It is not specified by design, but just for the sake of example I would say "I want it to be invoked if it can be invoked"

Comment: You need two different traits, one `has_name_function_member` and another `has_name_variable_member`,  Then you can use `if constexpr` to branch between the two different cases.  You can't have multiple specializations that get deduced to the same types which is why this fails as is.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess that with those two traits `if constexpr` would be an overkill. Moreover, I did not tag this question as c++17

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik The C++ tag means the current standard, which is C++20.  If you don't want that then you need to specify the max version.  Also, `void_t` is a C++17 feature.

Comment: @NathanOliver you are right, but `void_t` is a library feature, and `if constexpr` is a language feature.

Comment: Then you'll need to do the branching like we did before `if constexpr`.  My main point was that you can't have one trait that has three possibilities.  You only get one false case (`template <typename T, typename = void> struct _name;`), and one true case (`template <typename T> struct _name<T, void> { ... };`).

Comment: @NathanOliver I can't have 3 values for a boolean, that is true. But I can have as many specializations as I want. So theoretically if I make a primary template with default parameter `typeanme T, typename = get_specialization<T>`, I can go without `if constexpr`. But I am not sure

Comment: Related/possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45948990 (Seems like the fix is `template<class...> struct non_deduced_void { using type = void; }; template<class... T> using non_deduced_void_t = typename non_deduced_void<T...>::type;` or `type_identity_t<std::void_t<decltype(...)>>`)

Comment: @Artyer it is a very useful answer in the context of the current question. Thank you. However I would rather have a working solution for this specific problem.

Comment: `template <typename T> decltype(auto) name(const T &t) { return std::invoke(&T::name, t); }` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oaG4xGY86).

Comment: If you want to do it the hard way, then perhaps something [along these lines](https://godbolt.org/z/7rePbM97j)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik very nice. Can you post it as an answer? I wasn't aware of `std::invoke` being able to do these things. Very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be reinventing `std::invoke`. This function embodies the definition of [*Callable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) concept, and that definition has two special cases:

- a pointer to data member is "callable" like a function taking the object as its single parameter: `std::invoke(&C::dataMember, obj)` is equivalent to `obj.*dataMember`
- a pointer to member function is "callable" like a function taking the object as its first parameter: `std::invoke(&C::memFun, obj, a, b, c)` is equivalent to `(obj.*memFun)(a, b, c)`

Putting this together, your `name` can be implemented simply as

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) name(const T &t)
{
    return std::invoke(&T::name, t);
}
```

It will do the right thing whether `name` is a data member or a member function. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oaG4xGY86)

---

If you want `_name` as a customization point, just add an extra indirection: make `name` call `_name`, and the default implementation of `_name` call `std::invoke`.